# Excel: Obtain a column by sorting anotr one values

Tags: excel

I need to automatically obtain a sorted column of values from another given column values, like in the sample:

```
I have  I need A unchanged, and also B obtained from A
   A      A B
-----------------
   1      1 0
   0      0 0
   3      3 1
   8      8 3
   0      0 8
```

I mean if the values from A changes, the B should change accordignly...

Is that possible in MS Excel?

Here a sandbox and sample: 
http://1drv.ms/1SkqMhS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put The formula `=SMALL(A:A,ROW())` in `B1` and copy down then the cells in `B` will be linked to the cells in `A` in such a way that the numbers in `B` will be the numbers in `A` in sorted order. This won't be efficient for larger ranges but will work fine for small to medium size ranges.

If you want the numbers to start in a lower row, say `B2` because you have a header in `B1`, adjust `ROW()` to something like `ROW()-1`.

A word of warning: Use of `ROW()` can make a spreadsheet somewhat fragile in that formulas that involve it can change their meaning if rows are inserted or deleted or the block containing the formula is moved to somewhere else. Rather than using `ROW()`, there is something to be said for adding a helper column which numbers the data in `A` (which would then be in e.g. `B`) and referring to these numbers rather than small. For example, in:

[image]

If I put the formula

```
=SMALL($B$2:$B$5,A2)
```

In `C1` and copy down, it works as intended. In response to a question you raised in the comments, I added still another column which gives an index where the corresponding value occurs. To do this I wrote in `D2` (then copied) the formula

```
=MATCH(C2,$B$2:$B$5,0)
```

Comment: the something was not 1, but -1, also need to conserve the range, like `=SMALL(A$2:A$5,-1+ROW())`

Comment: Just in case you know: is there a way to find not just the value, but also the row number of the resp. smallest cell?

Comment: In C2 have `=1 + MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$6,0)` and copy down. This does roughly what you want -- but if a value occurs multiple times in the $A$-range then `MATCH` function will give the index of the *first* occurrence of the number in the range. You would either need an array function or at the very least a helper column or two if you want to do better than that. It would be sufficiently involved that you might want to post a separate follow-up question if you can't make the `MATCH` solution do what you want.

Comment: I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35059609/961631, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Highlight your range and in the Data tab, click ["Sort"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654), then you can choose how you want to sort your data:

[image]

If column B has information that is to be used with Column A (like next to A1 is "Car"), and you want to sort the whole table, based on Column A, then just select Columns A and B, then sort by column A.

Comment: I don't need to sort the column A... I need to have in the Column B sorted values from column A

Comment: @Serge - Can't you copy column A to column B, then run the above on column B?  I guess I don't understand actually what you're looking for...Can you clarify in your OP?

Comment: I have some calculation results in column A... Don't need to be altered... In the column B I need to sort the column A values and attribute a range for each value... I need to automate this for several columns, I can't copy-paste, cause loose automation...

Comment: @Serge - Can you please add more information to your original post? Can you clarify what you mean by "attribute a range for each value"?  Can you perhaps post a more robust example of what you're looking to do?  I suggest reading over [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I exposed very clear what I want, by the way the second asnwer is helpful. I have a column A with dynamic values, I need in the Column B having always the values from column A, but sorted.

Comment: @Serge - It would have been helpful to know you're not using Excel.  Also, how do you want them sorted? Alphabetically? Reverse numerical? Etc....

Comment: I Am using Excel. As you can see from the sample I gave in the OP is a simple numerical ascendent sort.1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, thanks to John Coleman !

Just some minor details like cell value fixing (with $, like `A$2`)and the `-1`+ROW  adjustment for the 1 header row!

[image]