# Excel: Obtain the row of the smaller value

Tags: excel

I have the following columns:
A - Original values, B - Absolute values, C - sorted absolute values

(I obtain the ordered values (C) using the `SMALL` formula for the given range - see the link bellow)

I need to know for each ordered absolute value, if the original value was or not negative: [image]

So in the picture the red columns I filled-in manually...
Is there a way to automatize that via a formula ?

Here is the link to the sandbox in Excel Online: http://1drv.ms/1Vu2MZ4
If the first link does not work, the same thing and formulas [on Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZYZeZFXrFW6HLgsQaQCVDJq4p2LslPCecC5uaYl_4NA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you got any code so far? If so please post it.

Comment: What kind of code? I mean, the formula is the in the online sandbox (see the link in the OP)

Comment: Are the original numbers all integers (positive or negative)? I have a trick that works in that case (but would fail if the numbers are sometimes decimals).

Comment: Added the Google Sheets link... The original numbers are all integers. Negative or positive this is NEG column should indicate.

Comment: Would be cool if the `SMALL` function also returned the cell information (row)

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer, which might be enough if column E in your screenshot is what you want and column D was a helper column intended to make column E easy to compute.

The problem with `ABS()` is that it loses information. Instead of using that, use a function which doesn't lose information but also doesn't change the sort order and which makes it possible to recover the absolute value after sorting. One way is to leave positive numbers alone but send negative numbers to their absolute value + 0.5. For example,

[image]

In `B2` enter

```
=IF(A2 >= 0,A2, 0.5+ABS(A2))
```

In `C2` enter

```
=SMALL($B$2:$B$6,-1+ROW())
```

In `D2` enter

```
=INT(C2)
```

To recover the absolute values. Finally, in `E2` enter

```
=IF(C2=D2,FALSE,TRUE)
```

(copying all of the formulas down).

Comment: The problem here is that the sorting is broken with this 0.5... because I need negative and positive values be ranked as the same if absolute values equals

Comment: @Serge  But -- the final ranking is in the `ABS` column and in that case they *are* ranked the same -- the `Int()` function strips away the decimal part leaving numbers which only differ by a sign ranked the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your case and for your locale `=MATCH(C2; $B$2:$B$6; 0)` and `= INDEX($A$2:$A$6; MATCH(C2; $B$2:$B$6; 0)) < 0` will do but beware of cases where you have the same value both negative and positive.